# How to reuse a JSP with a controller?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, controller

I'm new to web development with Java, so please excuse me if I'm butchering the terminology:

I'm building a web app with JSPs/servlets using the Java MVC model. I'm including a register/login option on the top menu that will of course need to communicate with the server (handle registering/logging in or retreiving the user's name).

I want to reuse both the JSP and controller code for the top menu as it should be on every page. I'm able to reuse the menu page using `<c:import>`. However, the menu will appear on pages that have their own functionality and therefore their own controllers. I can't figure out how to reuse the controller code for the menu on these pages as I can only map one servlet to a URL.

I don't have much code to show as an example at this point. What's the best practice for reusing common functionality like this without interfering with page specific functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly.

What about passing a hidden field in your form(which, from my understanding would point to the same mapping in your controller) specifying which jsp the request is coming from ? That way you know which jsp to call back from your controller.